# Oracle, need help understanding to_number and to_date functions

Tags: oracle

I been working with a complex view written by some other company in 2005. I am trying to understand what it is doing for reasons beyond this post. By the highly complex nature of this view (over 500 lines of code) I take it that the writers new what they where doing.

I keep finding things like TO_NUMBER(null), TO_DATE(null) in various places.

Seems to me like totally unnecessary use of a function.
Is there any technical reasons or advantages that justify why this was design like this?

Comment: My guess would be this is used to force a column that is null to have a specific datatype. Using just `null` doesn't guarantee a type if I'm not mistaken

Comment: It's like a man clapping his hands every few seconds to keep away the elephants. When you point out that there are no elephants, he just says: "See, it works!" This code solves problems that did not exist in the first place. It's superstitious.

Answer (score 2):

By default NULL does not have a data type:

```
SQL> select dump(null) from dual;

DUMP
----
NULL

SQL>
```

However, if we force Oracle into making a decision it will default to making it a string:

```
SQL> create or replace view v1 as
select 1 as id
       , null as dt
from dual
/
  2    3    4    5  
View created.

SQL> desc v1
 Name           Null?    Type
 -------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                      NUMBER
 DT                      VARCHAR2

SQL>
```

But this not always desirable.  We might need to use NULL in a view for a number of reasons (defining an API, filling out a jagged UNION, etc) and so we cast the NULL to another datatype to get the projection we need.

```
SQL> create or replace view v1 as
select 1 as id
       , to_date(null) as dt
from dual
/
  2    3    4    5  
View created.

SQL> desc v1
 Name           Null?    Type
 -------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                      NUMBER
 DT                      DATE

SQL>
```

Later versions have got smarter with regards to handling UNION.  On my 11gR2 database, even though I use the null in first declared query (and that usually drives things) I still get the correct datatype:

```
SQL> create or replace view v1 as
select 1 as id
       , null as dt
from dual
union all
select 2 as id
       , sysdate as something_else
from dual
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  
View created.

SQL> 
SQL> desc v1
 Name           Null?    Type
 -------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                      NUMBER
 DT                      DATE

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly casting `NULL` may be left over from 8i, or to workaround a bug, or as ammoQ said, "superstitious".

In some old and rare cases the implicit conversion of `NULL` in set operations caused errors like `ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`.
  I can't find any great references for this old behavior, but Google returns a few results that claim a query like this would fail in 8i:

```
select 'a' a from dual
union
select null a from dual;
```

And there is at least one similar bug, "Bug 9456979  Wrong result from push of NVL / DECODE into UNION view with NULL select list item - superceded".

But don't let 16 year-old software and some rare bug dictate how to program.  And don't think there's a positive correlation between code size programming skill.  There's a negative correlation: good programmers will create smaller, more readable code, and won't leave as many mysteries for future coders.

Comment: I think you might be on the right track. Your union example shows exactly how it was used. I also agree with you on the negative correlation between code size and programming skills. After spending the whole day reverse engineering this monster I have to say that it would have been more efficient if it was broken into smaller more manageable spices.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would prefer `CAST(NULL AS DATE)` or `CAST(NULL AS NUMBER)` instead of `TO_DATA(NULL)`, looks more logical in my eyes.

I know two scenarios where such an expression is required.
One it the case of UNION, as already stated in the other aswers.

Another scenario is the case of overloaded procedures/functions, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(val IN DATE) AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM EMP WHERE HIRE_DATE = val;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(val IN NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMP_ID = val;
END;
/
```

Calling the procedure like `MY_PROC(NULL);` does not work, Oracle does not know which procedure to execute. You must call it like `MY_PROC(CAST(NULL AS DATE));` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As a oracle PL/SQL programmer, I really don't find any logical reason for doing the things you have specified. The only logical approach to deal with `null` in oracle is to use `nvl()`, I really don't find any reason to use `TO_NUMBER(null)`, `TO_DATE(null)` in a complex view.